# How to insert a variable in path with python

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

trial = "hello"
save_path = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\hello.png"
sc1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
sc1.save(save_path)
```

I am trying to take screenshots and place them in my desktop. Is there a way to save the picture with different name by editing the name in the trial variable ?
i.e, like if I type **hey** in **trail** variable, the picture should be saved as **hey** in **desktop**.
I tried to modify the path but it did not work because, I think I cannot modify paths.

Answer (score 1):

Use f-string, this way:

```
import pyautogui

trial = "hey"
save_path = f"C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\{trial}.png"
sc1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
sc1.save(save_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help:-

```
import pyautogui

trial = "hello"
save_path = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\{}.png".format(trial)
sc1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
sc1.save(save_path)
```